# Poser-like plugin to help with drawing human figure in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing, perspective, plugin

Is there a plugin that gives you a poser (human figure) to play with in Adobe Illustrator, sort of like the perspective grid tool but with an actual human you can rig and move the camera around?

Like [Poser](http://poser.smithmicro.com/) or [MakeHuman](http://www.makehuman.org/)

Complicated POVs on the human body take a long time to master! :( If I could rig a character in the position I want it will look realistic and I can draw on top of it, then remove it.

[image: Like this!]
*Like this but with controls to alter the position and POV.*

Comment: Illustrator is not a real 3D application. Why can't you just rig it in Poser, export it, and draw over it?

Comment: There are plenty of figure pose references in e.g. the bookstore. You don't mention the intended use, but the problem with 3d is that it is easy to come up with poses that are completely unnatural, even if they conform in all ways to normal human range of motion.

Comment: I think you might have to look not in the designer-community, but there is a chance that say educational institutions have developed something like that. That is just not very publicly announced. Having said that; other software more geared towards "real" 3D will have loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

I've never seen anything related to automated figure drawing with Illustrator, 3D or otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

use manga studio. its has a 3d model where you can pose it as you wish and then draw on it.